# using -std=c++0x causes error: ‘Iterator’ does not name a type error

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm trying to compile a previously working code
to the `c++11` standard. I did this by just putting

```
-std=c++0x
```

in the `Makevars` file.

Now, the compiler complaints,
giving me this error:

```
29:43: error: ‘Iterator’ does not name a type
29:58: error: ‘Iterator’ has not been declared
29:75: error: ‘Iterator’ does not name a type
```

This is the offending line:

```
extern inline bool nextone(const Iterator first,Iterator k,const Iterator last);
```

what should I add to the code to fix this?

## edit:

The original declaration of the function is

```
template <typename Iterator>
inline bool nextone(const Iterator first, Iterator k, const Iterator last){
///does things
}
```

Comment: `#include <iterator>` ? `nextone` could be a template-ed function though.

Comment: @POW: adding #include <iterator> didn't change anything (the problem stays). I don't understand your second sentence.

Comment: Well `nextone` appears to be something like `template<typename Iterator> bool nextone(const Iterator first,Iterator k,const Iterator last) { /* code */  } `

Comment: @user189035: `extern inline bool nextone(const Iterator first,Iterator k,const Iterator last);` is that all you had ? how did it compile without `Iterator` type ? you have not posted everuthing

Comment: @user189035: did you change anything else except for compiler option? (personally I doubt)

Comment: @PiotrS.: no, I don t think so. But I won t be able to check for sure before tuesday /

Comment: `extern inline bool nextone(const Iterator first,Iterator k,const Iterator last);` is not valid without `template<typename Iterator>` before it

Comment: To get better answers post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), should be pretty easy to construct one for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that `nextone` will be instantiated somewhere else, use [*extern template*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) to force the compiler to not instantiate it, reducing compile time and object code size.

```
extern template <typename Iterator> 
inline bool nextone(const Iterator first,Iterator k,const Iterator last);
```